# Setting more than one variable to the same value in c++

Tags: c++, statements

I had a question about if I could set more than one variable to the same value like this:

```
int hours, minutes, seconds, TotalTimeInSeconds = 12;
```

or if I had to type it in like this:

```
int hours = 12, minutes = 12, seconds = 12, TotalTimeInSeconds = 12;
```

thank you!

Comment: You have to do it the second way.

Comment: in c++ 17 you may also use `auto [hours, minutes, seconds] = { 12, 12, 12};`
`

Answer (score 2):

well what you can do is

```
int hours, minutes, seconds, TotalTimeInSeconds;
hours=minutes=seconds=TotalTimeInSeconds=12
```

& to explain how does that exactly work

in this example

```
int a,b;
a=b=2;
```

what's actually happening is

```
a.operator=(b.operator=(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first suggestion only assigns 12 to `TotalTimeInSeconds`.

The closest way of doing this could be:

```
int hours, minutes, seconds, TotalTimeInSeconds;
hours = minutes = seconds = TotalTimeInSeconds = 12;
```